# How to make list from text file in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, text-files

I have txt file and I want to import text to list in Python.
Txt file(If need I can change it):
Hi, Hello, Welcome
And I want list like that:
['Hi','Hello','Welcome']

Comment: Eh I tryied somethink like that:

Comment: filename = 'Test-file.txt' 
file=open(filename,'r')
L1list = file.readline()

Comment: @Simon edit your question with that code

Comment: Edit your question and show your attempt, don't put it in comments.

Comment: I put the exact headline into Google and got a ton of hits.

Comment: Read about [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and try to write some code!

Comment: I am sorry if this duplicate :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

```
print open('yourfile.txt').read().split(',')
```

And if you're not sure about extra spaces or tabs in your source file, you can remove them:

```
print map(str.strip, open('yourfile.txt').read().split(','))
```

Comment: Txt to u that sloved my problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
>>>hmm="Welcome And I want list like that"
>>>my_list=hmm.split()
>>>my_list
['Welcome', 'And', 'I', 'want', 'list', 'like', 'that']
```

Comment: OP specifically says a file.